# IllegalArgumentException In An AsyncTask On Rotate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have successfully sent an email in the background and displayed a progress dialog to the user as said email is sent. However when the user flips the screen while the dialog is up I get an IllegalArgumentException. I have tried using a WeakReference object and it doesn't seem to be fixing the problem. This is my AsyncTask class.

```
private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Mail, String, EmailStatusResponce> {

    private final WeakReference<ProgressDialog> weakReference;


    public SendMailTask() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SendReportActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sending...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        weakReference = new WeakReference<>(progressDialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected EmailStatusResponce doInBackground(Mail... mail) {
        return mail[0].send();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(EmailStatusResponce result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null && weakReference != null) {
            weakReference.get().dismiss();     // This is where the exception is thrown.

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SendReportActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else  {}
        }
    }
```

This is the exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{688d3e2 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} not attached to window manager

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

EDIT: More logcat

> --------- beginning of crash
>   12-11 16:22:40.154    1976-1976/com.blazapps.allenfamilymedicine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.blazapps.allenfamilymedicine, PID: 1976
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f89e667 V.E...... R......D 0,0-760,232} not attached to window manager
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
>               at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:362)
>               at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:345)
>               at com.blazapps.allenfamilymedicine.SendReportActivity$SendMailTask.onPostExecute(SendReportActivity.java:168)
>               at com.blazapps.allenfamilymedicine.SendReportActivity$SendMailTask.onPostExecute(SendReportActivity.java:138)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Post more messages of your LogCat ("Caused by" section)

Comment: I added the information you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do no know why the exception is being thrown but because I save lots of information in EmailStatusResponse I can just surround the exception with a try catch and if the task was complete I get the result I expected.

```
try {
    weakReference.get().dismiss();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

If anyone can figure a better solution I would really appreciate it. I hate just catching exceptions. There is usually a better way.